# Profile Manager: Mass Deploying Exchange Accounts

Tags: ios, mail.app, server.app, exchange

Many of my users would like to set up their Exchange accounts (which are provided by company) on their personal iPhones or iPads. None of the iPhones and iPads are enrolled to my macOS Server. I would like to try Profile Manager (from macOS Server) to create a profile configuration for mass deployment, in order to reduce repetitive labor.

There are some information to be inputted when creating the configuration file. Here is the correct configuration which works for me. But I can't 'mass configure' Exchange settings of ***Users*** or ***Email*** ***Address***. It seems the only way we can preconfigure Exchange for each user is to create a profile for each individual user.

[image]

[image]

You may have heard of the part of Profile Manager documentation covering global variables that you can use to configure group profiles: [Payload variables](http://help.apple.com/profilemanager/mac/10.7/#apd073333AA-30C6-4FD2-B2E0-E0C95658A2C4). I did give it a try. But it seems it doesn't work for me. Here is how it looks like:

[image]
[image]

***Anyone know how to get it work? Any suggestions would be appreciated.***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me answer this by myself. Try to create a profile configuration via ***Groups*** instead of ***Devices Groups.*** Here is what it looks like:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I believe the %AD_Domain% and related variables only work with 802.1x payloads. For the User field, does the domain change? If not you can use something like:

mydomain\%first_name%.%last_name%

That is, manually enter the domain and use variables for the rest...

Comment: See my answer belowing